# Find a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ if and only if k does not equal __

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The vectors
> $$\vec{v}_1=\begin{bmatrix}6\\-6\\0\end{bmatrix} , \ \ \ \vec{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}-5\\3\\-7\end{bmatrix} , \ \ \ \vec{v}_3=\begin{bmatrix}19\\-21\\k\end{bmatrix}$$
> form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ if and only if $k\ne \ ?$.

I've been trying to solve this and I'm not getting anywhere. The k is really throwing me off. I row reduce and I get down to: \begin{bmatrix}6&0&14\\0&1&-1\\0&0&-7+k\end{bmatrix}

I'm a bit (a lot) lost.

Comment: You have a basis if and only if the rank of the row-reduced matrix is...? And the row reduced matrix has that rank unless $k=$...?

Comment: You should augment your matrix with the zero column vector making it a homogeneous system. If the trivial solution is the only solution then all vectors are independent and the set will span R^3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach. Since $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent, the only way that adding $v_3$ does **not** make a basis is if $v_3 \in \operatorname{sp} \{ v_1, v_2 \}$.

So, try to solve $v_3 = x_1 v_2 + x_2 v_2 $ in order to find the $k$ that
makes this possible.

Solving the top two rows gives $x_1 = 4$, $x_2= 1$, and these are unique.

Hence the collection does not form a basis **iff**
$k = x_1 \cdot 0 + x_2 \cdot (-7) = -7$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your row reduction has sign errors in the 2,3 and 3,3 entries.  I'm able to row reduce to the form
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 6 & 0 & 14 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 7+k \end{array} \right)
$$
The original three vectors are linearly dependent if and only if this matrix is singular.  This matrix is triangular, so its determinant is the product of its diagonal entries, hence singular if and only if $k=-7$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:I suggest it is not a bad idea to find the determinant for a 3 by 3 matrix, because it does not inquire a astronaumic amount of calculation.**
Here is how I do this.
**The basic idea is that I have to find the value of k that for which those three vectors are linear dependent.**
So I create a matrix which is $A=\left[\begin{matrix}\vec{v_1}&\vec{v_2}&\vec{v_3}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}6&-5&19\\-6&3&-21\\0&-7&k\end{matrix}\right]$
If those three vectors are linear dependent then we have the three columns of the matrix A to be linear dependent, so in this case we have the determinant of matrix A to be zero, for the third definition of linear algebra called the multi-linearity.
Then we have $detA=det\left[\begin{matrix}6&-5&19\\-6&3&-21\\0&-7&k\end{matrix}\right]=6\left[\begin{matrix}3&-21\\-7&k\end{matrix}\right]+6\left[\begin{matrix}-5&19\\-7&k\end{matrix}\right]=6(3k-147)+6(-5k+133)=0$
So it is solved out to be $k=-7$.
I hope it will help.